# Persist global yarn to call Jhipster

Tags: macos, terminal, jhipster, yarnpkg

**Overview**
I'm learning Java and JHipster.  I installed JHipster and have a project but when I try to call Jhipster from the Mac terminal I get this error:

```
-bash: jhipster: command not found
```

Now I found this command in another question here and when I add this the jhipster command works.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin):$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin"
```

but only works that time and I have to do it every time.

**Questions**

- Right way to install yarn o jhipster?
- alternative to make the global jhipster persistent on my folder

**Notes**

- I'm really new at this so if I miss something just tell me on the comments and I will add the info to the question.
- In the Intellij IDEA terminal the jhipster command works and says something like "using jhipster installed globally"

Comment: You need to add the `$PATH` to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @l'L'l thank you that totally fix it 

Answer (score 1):

Just like @l'L'l says I just have to add it to the `~/.bash_profile`

that fix the problem